# Multiprocessing Pool() method has no effect on performance

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am using Python 3.9.2 on Linux/Debian testing, on a multiprocessor machine. I am trying to understand how multiprocessing works.

I wrote two simple scripts that perform two exponential functions, one without multiprocessing and the other with.

This is the one without multiprocessing:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer


def sqr(n):

    a = n ** n

    return a


def sqr_2(m):

    b = m ** m

    return b


def main():

    start = timer()
    
    print(f'sqr = {sqr(100000)}\nsqr_2= {sqr_2(200000)}')
    
    end = timer()


    print(f'time frame in which the operation is resolved: {end - start} seconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this is the script using multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from timeit import default_timer as timer


def sqr_1(n):

    return n ** n


def sqr_2(m):

    return m ** m


def main():

    cpu_cnt = cpu_count()
    pool = Pool(processes = cpu_cnt)     #In this case there are 12 processors

    start = timer()
    
    val_1 = (100000,)
    val_2 = (200000,)
    
    process_1 = pool.map_async(sqr_1, val_1)
    process_2 = pool.map_async(sqr_2, val_2)
    
    print(f'Results: {process_1.get(), process_2.get()}')

    end = timer()

    print(f'time frame in which the operation is resolved: {end - start} seconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that the process of the second script, which finished without any error, performed the same task as the first script in the same amount of time (around 14 seconds). So the multiprocessing, in the second script, does not work. I thank in advance anyone who would like to point out that is the error!

Comment: You're going to need to do a LOT more work than a single math operation in each process, to justify the time it takes to launch a process.  And note that your times include the conversion of the math results to decimal, which is all happening in the main process (and likely to take longer than the math itself).

Comment: You misunderstand.  When you use a  multiprocessing pool, the library has to launch a new process, with a new copy of the interpreter, which has to re-initialize itself from the beginning.  It then has to reload your script, and only then can it run your function.  Right now, you are having each process run ONE exponentiation operator.  The cost of launching and initializing that new interpreter is many thousands of times higher than the cost of your one function.  You need to DO MORE STUFF in your `sqr` functions if you want to see the benefits.

Comment: With 2 calls to `sqr`, the serial/parallel scripts both run (skipping the actual output of the result, which is the most time-consuming part) in 0.3 seconds on my machine. Bump that up to 6 calls, and the split becomes 4.3 seconds vs 2.1 seconds. There's always some overhead to parallelization, but that overhead becomes less significant the more work you can actually *do* in parallel.

Comment: Very intersting, thank you.. in fact if I don't print the numerical result (useless thing, but I wanted to be sure that it did this operation) the result with the pool arrives after only 0,14 sec

Comment: ..in fact without print the numerical result, if I increasing of one zero both operands, I get the result of the operation in 9 seconds with the script without pool and in 6 seconds with the other script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following script. It lets you choose at runtime how many times to call the function, and whether to do so serially or in parallel. It also just computes the value; it does not try to write a string representation to standard output (since converting the result of `n**n` to a string is far more time-consuming for large `n` than actually calculating it).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import sys


def f(n):
    return n ** n


def main():
    cpu_cnt = cpu_count()
    n = int(sys.argv[2])
    start = timer()
    if sys.argv[1] == "s":
        s = [f(100000) for _ in range(n)]
    else:
        pool = Pool(processes = cpu_cnt)
        s = [pool.map_async(f, (100000,)) for _ in range(n)]
        results = [x.get() for x in s]
    end = timer()
    print(f'time frame in which the operation is resolved: {end - start} seconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are the results for 2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, and 192 function calls on my 4-core machine:

```
% for n in 2 6 12 24 48 96 192; do print $n; for x in s p; do python3 tmp.py $x $n; done; done
2
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 0.146144435 seconds
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 0.178840965 seconds
6
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 0.423103791 seconds
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 0.24940852500000002 seconds
12
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 0.848754817 seconds
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 0.340022419 seconds
24
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 1.691312521 seconds
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 0.571664972 seconds
48
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 3.415401498 seconds
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 1.029526396 seconds
96
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 6.76773454 seconds
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 2.016387216 seconds
192
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 13.529949021999998 seconds
time frame in which the operation is resolved: 3.770171452 seconds
```

With only 2 parallel processes, there's no speed-up, due to the overhead of the parallelization itself. (In fact, there is a slow-down.) Once you start running more processes, the speed-up increases, though for `n` cores you will never quite see a speed-up of `n`.